# vuejs - Changing a computed property via a method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to adjust a computed property within a vue component inside a method. When this property changes I am trying to show/hide a `div`.  Currently when I perform the click event, I am seeing the correct boolean log under the `set` function, but not seeing any change to the `showBanner` prop.

Here's where I'm at.

HTML

```
<template>
  <div v-if="someConfig.displayBanner && showBanner" class="bn-banner">
    {{showBanner}}
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex';

  export default{

    name: "myComponentShell",

    computed: {
      ...mapState('utilitiesStore', [
        'someConfig'
        ]),

        styleObject () {
          return {
            background: this.someConfig.colorHex
          }
        },

    showBanner:{

      get () {
        return (this.someConfig.text === localStorage.getItem("gma_alerts_hide")) ? false : true
      },

      set (value) {
        console.log(value)
        return value
      }
    }


    },

    methods: {
      ...mapActions('utilitiesStore', [
          'getJSON'
        ]),

        closeBreaking () {
          localStorage.setItem("someData", this.someConfig.text)
          this.showBanner = false;
        }
    },

  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use && operator in your code to fixed "text is undefined" error

```
(this.someConfig && this.someConfig.text)
```

Inside this code:

```
data () {
return {
    showBanner: (this.someConfig.text === localStorage.getItem("gma_alerts_hide")) ? false : true
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because you're returning a value instead of assigning a value in your `set` method of `showBanner` computed property.

Try something like

```
set (value) {
  this.someConfig.text = value; // I assign a value so get() method will trigger
}
```

Keep in mind that `set`  method must modify something in order to see changes in `showBanner`

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

Answer (score -1):

`showBanner` is not truly a computed property, it is simply a variable who's state is initialized from a ternary. Therefore you should just declare it as a `data` property.

```
data () {
    return {
        showBanner: (this.someConfig.text === localStorage.getItem("gma_alerts_hide")) ? false : true
    }

}
```

Then `this.showBanner = false;` makes sense.

**Edit** Updated data declaration because you're using single file components.

Comment: tried this, but it throws another error `vue.esm.js:1687 TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined`

Comment: @gregdevs Where does `this.someConfig` come from? You would probably need `this.someConfig &&` or at least some type of test

Comment: ` this.someConfig` comes from `mapState` in computed.